# "Master's of Early Childhood Education" or "master's in early childhood education"

Tags: commas, capitalization

Is the capitalization and my use of an apostrophe okay in the following sentence?:

I am a part-time college student seeking my Master's degree in Early Childhood Education.

Comment: Looks good to me, except the ["greengrocer's apostrophe"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/greengrocer%27s_apostrophe) in **comma's**. Anyway, the sentence does not contain a comma. I would change "seeking my Master's..." to "reading a Master's..."

Comment: There are no commas in your sentence, only apostrophes, with which you properly formed a possessive with Master's but improperly a plural of coma, which is commas, not comma's.

Comment: @WeatherVane: "reading a Master's" is exclusively a UK expression.

Comment: @KarlG I think it's more accurately a Commonwealth expression, but it is very confusing to American readers.

Comment: If you look on LinkedIn, "Masters Degree" and "Master's Degree" are both used.  Conceptually, it can be the degree held by the master of a discipline, or by the masters of a discipline, in which case "Masters" is a noun modifier.

Comment: I don't think this is opinion based: https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11105/this-wasnt-an-opinon-based-question

Answer (score 2):

So this varies a lot more than I realized when I originally posted.

Here I'll try to explain what I think isn't so opinion-based, and also point out what can be.

---

Here's what can be said for sure.

1. Your use of an apostrophe is correct inasmuch as it's not "masters degree." I don't think anyone disputes that.
2. The field is not capitalized unless it is already a proper noun, like "English" or "Japanese."
3. That is, unless you're referring to the full, proper, name of your degree, in which case, the whole thing is capitalized.

> Last year at the University of X, 16 students graduated with a Master of Arts in Early Childhood Education.

4. If you are using the full name of the degree, there is no [genitive 's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_possessive). For example, see the Wikipedia [page on British degree abbreviations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_degree_abbreviations), which has a huge list of bachelor's and master's degrees, none of which have an *'s*.

---

However, if you don't want to use the proper name of your degree (it's pretty stuffy, after all), you have options on how to abbreviate it.

The 2014 AP Stylebook says:

> **Master of Arts, Master of Science, Master of Business Administration** ... A *master's degree* or a *master's* is acceptable in any reference.

and also

> **academic degrees** ... Use an apostrophe in *bachelor's degree*, *a master's* etc., but there is no possessive in *Bachelor of Arts* or *Master of Science*.

On the other hand, University College London [says](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/prospective-students/pams/audit-design/style-guide) ("//" added for clarity):

> USE // DO NOT USE
>
> Master’s degree // masters Degree
>
> first-class Bachelor's degree // First Class Honours Degree

So if you went to UCL you could say "my Master's degree in early childhood education," but if you went to [Western Michigan University](http://www.wmich.edu/writing/rules/capitalization), you would say "my master's degree ...." Furthermore, capitalized "Bachelor's" and "Master's" strikes me as very British but I don't have anything to back that up.

But, if you don't want to change the phrasing of your statement, you may optionally upper- or lower-case "master's" but shouldn't capitalize "Early Childhood Education."

Answer (score -2):

From my perspective, it looks right (using in). Just like saying "I have a Master's degree in Mathematics".

Comment: The capitalisation in your example doesn’t make sense.

Comment: This answer comes across as mere opinion.